# Save embedded PDFs in Word file

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need a VBA macro for MS Word 2013 to save the embedded PDF attachments in the Word file into a folder.

I found a working solution in Excel which saves embedded files in the Excel document, I have made some modifications to work in Word VBA, but it doesn't work any ideas to make it work in Word ?

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub RtlMoveMemory Lib "kernel32" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

Sub Embed_Files_Save_PDF_Run()
For Each file In ThisDocument.InlineShapes
Call Embed_Files_Save_PDF(file)
Next
End Sub

Sub Embed_Files_Save_PDF(ByVal Embedded_PDF)

      On Error Resume Next

      Dim PDF_Path As String
      PDF_Path = ActiveDocument.Path

      If Right$(PDF_Path, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then PDF_Path = PDF_Path & Application.PathSeparator

      Dim PDF_Name As String
      PDF_Name = UCase$(Left$(Embedded_PDF.OLEFormat.IconLabel, 1)) & Mid$(Embedded_PDF.OLEFormat.IconLabel, 2)    
      PDF_Name = PDF_Name & ".PDF"

      Dim FileEOF As Long
      Dim FileLOF As Long
      Dim CB_Lock As Long           ' ClipBoard Lock
      Dim CB_Size As Long           ' ClibBoard Size
      Dim PDF_File() As Byte
      Dim Temp_PDF() As Byte

      Embedded_PDF.Copy
      If OpenClipboard(0) Then
            Counter = GetClipboardData(49156)
            If Counter <> 0 Then CB_Size = GlobalSize(Counter)
            If CB_Size <> 0 Then CB_Lock = GlobalLock(Counter)
            If CB_Lock <> 0 Then
                  ReDim Temp_PDF(1 To CLng(CB_Size))
                  RtlMoveMemory Temp_PDF(1), ByVal CB_Lock, CB_Size
                  Call GlobalUnlock(Counter)
                  Counter = InStrB(Temp_PDF, StrConv("%PDF", vbFromUnicode))
                  If Counter > 0 Then
                        FileEOF = InStrB(Counter, Temp_PDF, StrConv("%%EOF", vbFromUnicode))
                        While FileEOF
                              FileLOF = FileEOF - Counter + 7
                              FileEOF = InStrB(FileEOF + 5, Temp_PDF, StrConv("%%EOF", vbFromUnicode))
                        Wend

                        ReDim PDF_File(1 To FileLOF)
                        For FileEOF = 1 To FileLOF
                              PDF_File(FileEOF) = Temp_PDF(Counter + FileEOF - 1)
                        Next
                  End If
            End If
            CloseClipboard
            If Counter > 0 Then
                  Counter = FreeFile
                  Open PDF_Path & PDF_Name For Binary As #Counter
                        Put #Counter, 1, PDF_File
                  Close #Counter
            End If
      End If

      Set Embedded_PDF = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you are missing the `if` command line  ... the code that you posted cannot possibly be `code to reach the objects`

Comment: ok `endif` deleted i can get object names i will edit the question

Comment: what is the file extension of the word doc file? how many files are you processing?

Comment: Word file extension is .doc, i have nearly 20 word files to process and all of them have only 1 PDF embedded file.

Comment: this may work ... open doc with 7-zip and navigate to word\media folder ... if you do not have 7-zip then add `.zip` to the filename  `myDoc.docm.zip`, then open with windows explorer

Comment: double clicking the acrobat object in the word document opens it in acrobat viewer, then you can save it .... i am still checking for VBA code that would do the job

Comment: .doc file format is not a zip archive: save as docx first...

Comment: Thanks for ideas, I have found a solution for Excel and edited my question further to adapt this to Word.

Answer (score 0):

try this

it does not save the pdf file but it opens it in acrobat so that you can save it

```
Sub pdfExtract()

    ' opens embedded pdf file in acrobat reader for saving

    Dim shap As InlineShape

    For Each shap In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If Not shap.OLEFormat Is Nothing Then
            If shap.OLEFormat.ClassType = "AcroExch.Document.DC" Then
                shap.OLEFormat.DoVerb wdOLEVerbOpen
            End If
        End If
    Next shap
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but what i require is to run a macro (from Excel or Word doesn't matter) and save the embedded attachments in the Word file by this macro without user interference, i have edited my question further to show where i got stuck.